# How to enable searching an attachment's content in a google site

Tags: search, google-sites

The goal: I am wanting to be able to search attachments' contents located on my google site via my site's search box. Attachments such as a google doc or google sheet's contents.

The problem: So I have a file cabinet on my google site which is populated with files from some folders in my google drive. If I search for a keyword in a document on my google site, the search returns with no results. If I do the exact same search in my google drive, I get the result I expected. Is there a way to enable this functionality in my google site?

Answer (score 0):

I have not found a way for files loaded into the file cabinet *via Google Drive* to be searchable. However, if you upload files in their native format (.docx, .pdf, etc.) from your local disk they are parsed, indexed and then searchable.

Answer (score 0):

I not possible to search a file into Cabinet , if you want a solution , you take this gadget.

https://docs.google.com/a/essilor.fr/document/d/1G9JiOOFT5VKYGITvrLdlv0pBnJM0rXdrruSd91zAcCM/edit

You have some data on your spreadsheet ( data , file , ... ) and This gadget show your data.
Simple and better if you want StringFilter and other Filters , and your file is on your drive.